# Will I get electrocuted if I contact a live wire on an earthed appliance?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I have an appliance that has the wires connected well and it has been grounded (earthed). If I accidentally get into contact with a live wire will I get electrocuted considering it has already been earthed?

Answer (score 2):

You may not be electrocuted, but you will surely be shocked if you provide a path from hot to ground. Grounding (earthing) a device helps prevent you from being shocked by touching the equipment. If you grab hold of the live wire, the equipment being grounded (earthed) will not help you.

Comment: To clarify: The ground protects being shocked by the device *if there is an internal wiring fault*: instead of becoming energized waiting for a path to ground (eg, you) to come along, the chassis is already grounded and the resulting current flow will trip the breaker immediately. If you are touching a grounded appliance and then grab a live wire with your other hand, it's much, much worse: you'll form a *really good* path to ground that involves electricity travelling across your chest/heart, and there's a very high chance you'll be dead within a couple seconds.